# scheduled web synchronization with MS Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have settled a web synchronization between SQLSERVER 2005 as publisher and SQLEXPRESS as suscriber. Web synchro has to be launched manually through IE interface (menu tools/synchronize) and to be selected among available synchronizations.

Everything is working fine except that I did not find a way to automate the synchro, which I still have to launch manually. Any idea?

I have no idea if this synchro can be launched from SQLEXPRESS by running a specific T-SQL code (in this case my problem could be solved indirectly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denny Cherry, a SQL Server MVP, is writing a replacement for SQL Server Agent.

- [Denny's blog about it](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/tag/standalone-sql-agent/)
- [His Standalone SQL Agent project on Codeplex](http://standalonesqlagent.codeplex.com/)

Using this, you would be able to automatically initiate code on a scheduled basis.  But it's either this, or writing your own .NET app to kick off jobs.  SQL Server Express Edition doesn't include any kind of automated job scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know about SQL Server web synchronization, but as SQL Express don't have an SQL Server Agent, you can write a C# console application that runs with the scheduled tasks.